# Error's with dpkg when trying to reinstall chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dpkg

Noob here,

When attempting to uninstall google chrome from terminal I first encountered the error. Since I tried updating resulting in the same error.

Here is an example:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
After this operation, 180 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any help would be muchly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After much googling, I was unable to find good directions for my specific problem.  Because the Error did not point to a specific package that was causing problems, I was unsure how to correct the problem.  After playing with some dpkg commands I received an error that pointed to the libept1.4.12:amd64 from there I followed the oft given instructions for dpkg errors:

- `gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`
- Search for the offending package (`libept1.4.12`) by name and remove its entry.
- Save the file and exit Gedit.
- run `sudo apt-get -f install`.
- Continue on if there are no errors.

Now its fixed. I can now update, remove and install chrome, and even download new software huzzah! If you have a similar problem with dpkg but cannot figure out the package causing the problems, I recommend using dpkg commands from the dpkg main page until you figure out the problem package...